# How to use symbols such as \delta and \lambda

Tags: symbols, compiling, syntax

I'm trying to use symbols such as `\lambda` and `\delta` but for some reason it's not compiling. I've reproduced the problem in the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

M = < X,Y,S,ta, \delta int, \delta ext, \lambda >

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Missing $ inserted M = < X,Y,S,ta, \delta

Missing $ inserted I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think

Missing } inserted I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup
```

Despite these errors, I can still view it in a PDF and it looks like the following:

[image: The output of above code]

So, just to clarify what I actually want:

1. To compile without the errors i.e. how do you make use of symbols like `\delta` etc?
2. How do I actually make it display like the following :

   [image]
3. As depicted above, I want `int` and `ext` to be subscripts to the `\delta` symbols

Comment: First, you need to surround the relevant line with `$` symbols.  Second, use underscores to create subscripts (and, for multiple-character subscripts, use curly braces as well).  Thus, `$M = < X,Y,S,ta, \delta_{int}, \delta_{ext}, \lambda >$`

Comment: @AndrewUzzell `<` and `>` in this case are definitely wrong.

Comment: @egreg You're absolutely right.  Also, when I posted my comment, I hadn't realized that the question was asking for how to typeset a displayed equation.  In sum, egreg's answer is much more useful than my comment.

Comment: This question shouldn't be downvoted. It may be a basic problem, but the question itself is very clear. Please don't downvote without explaining your reason to do so.

Comment: In addition to Jake's comment, unlike SO in general, beginner questions are more than welcome in TeX.SE so please don't downvote if the question seems trivial to you. The question has a valid MWE and a good formulation.

Comment: @Jake: But he didn't even read the help messages TeX gave him.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I did read the help messages that TEX gave me. This was in fact the first error message(s) I got since I started using TEX very recently. The reason why I put the question here in the first place was because I didn't understand what the error messages wanted me to do. I tried putting in $ which didn't work for me. However, thanks to egreg's answer and reference he gave me, I'm now getting very familiar with the whole math mode concept and many other new things. So definitely worth it and I disagree with down voting the question. You have to start from some where.

Comment: @Jatt: I didn't downvote. `:-)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want a centered formula; so the correct way to do it is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\begin{document}

\[
M = \langle X, Y, S, ta, \delta_{\mathrm{int}}, \delta_{\mathrm{ext}}, \lambda \rangle
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is covered in any basic LaTeX manual, for example [The not so short introduction to LaTeX](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lshort-english/lshort.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. But what is the reason behind not using \begin{center}? and why was my question down voted, so I know what I did wrong?

Comment: `center` is for centering *text*, not math. I don't know why the question was downvoted; however, it's very basic and reading an introduction to LaTeX would really help to understand its principles, which are rather different from common word processors.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for the reference as well, will use it for any further issues before I ask on here again..

Comment: @Jatt My comment was not meant for restraining you from asking here even basic level questions. Everybody is welcome, in my opinion. The fact is that LaTeX needs a different attitude than word processors; its main principle is separation of structure from visual appearance, so math is different from text and this reflects in how they're input.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will look further into it. 
Ps. Your comment did not at all restrain me from asking questions in the future. I agree with you, I should've researched more before asking for help.